# Programmatically find device support GPS or not?

Tags: android

I am trying to find some code which will help me to find out if the device which I use has GPS or not? I don't want to know if GPS is enabled or disabled. I just want to know if the device has GPS hardware or not through my program.

Comment: Note: You should probably "accept" some answers to your previous questions.  You do this by clicking the green "tick" icon next to the best answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

You can call [`LocationManager.getAllProviders()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getAllProviders%28%29) and check whether `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` is included in the list.

Just for reference, I believe all released Android phones come with a GPS.  It's not something that Android seem to be worrying about, e.g. mentioning GPS as one of the device attributes returned by [`PackageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getSystemAvailableFeatures%28%29).

Comment: They do currently all have GPS but some tablets in the future might not (I think the K-Mart tablet doesn't actually).

Comment: @RockOn If you find this answered your question, can you accept it?

Comment: @Mike: The Kindle Fire didn't exist in April 2010, but as of SDK version 8 you can use the `PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS` constant with the `getSystemAvailableFeatures()` method mentioned here.

Comment: Many low cost phones of *itel* manufacturer from China do have Android without any GPS sensor; an example is their model it1353.

Comment: @DanielBeauyat Indeed. But that wasn't the case over five years ago when I wrote this answer, as you can also see from the comment above yours.

Answer (score 10):

Those methods are easier to use:

```
private boolean hasGpsSensor(){
        PackageManager packMan = getPackageManager();
        return packMan.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
}
```

- `true`: available (activated or not)
- `false`: not available

So, in case of `true`, we can use

```
private boolean isGpsEnabled(){
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

- `true`: enabled
- `false`: disabled

With this two, you will know if GPS is available, activated or deactivated

Comment: Short. Concise. True. Good answer to OP. Very Informative. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There's also LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(String provider) method.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Quote from question: "I don't want to know if GPS is enabled or disabled.".